# Unable to find explicit activity class error. The different between these two codes

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

Just want to ask whats the different if i call an intent like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("com.zeta.workorder", "com.zeta.workorder.ListActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
```

I had try the first one and i got the "unable to find explicit activity class" error. It work find before on my other apps. But for this app, i need to use the second code or else i got the error. what could be the problem here? here is my manifest for this app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zeta.workorder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.zeta.workorder.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zeta.workorder.ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat error

```
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:    Unable to find explicit activity class {com.zeta.workorder/android.app.ListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3561)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3529)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.zeta.workorder.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
03-18 16:50:52.460: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you paste all of the error log? your code is current.

Comment: Sure. i have add the logcat error

Comment: @Wan999 please show what's inside the `<manifest>` tag, especially `package` attribute

Comment: @nikis sure. i have included the full manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it ! Please rename your ListActivity.java

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
}
```

then you can try first one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: ListActivity is also the name of a class provided in the android framework, that might be the reason.

Comment: oh i didn't know that. thank you so much. the first method works now

Answer (score 0):

please do like below,

```
 intent = new Intent();
      //first parameter is package, not a package where it is
        intent.setClassName("com.zeta", "com.zeta.workorder.ListActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: actually, i was asking why the first method won't work but the second method works

Comment: sorry for the mess,please add   intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); before call the startActivity(intent);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i still got the same error

Comment: please try, Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ListActivity.class);
  intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);

Comment: u can use getbasecontext() or getApplicationcontext()

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ListActivity.class);
  intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is very funny: by specifying just `ListActivity.class` you intersect with this built-in class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html which is shown in error - android.app.ListActivity. Just rename `ListActivity`and both methods will work.